# How do I add checkboxes inside a dropdown in Excel or Google Sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I would like to have the data validation that is possible with having a dropdown but I would like to have more than one selection.

Is is possible for a cell dropdown to have checkboxes beside the dropdown elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead of Dropdown box, List box is best suitable to add Check boxes for multiple selection.**

*Let me explain how to do this in Excel (most of Excel commands & methods are applicable to Google Sheet also.)*

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Click **Developer Tab, Insert, List Box** 
   (from Active X Control).
2. After you draw the List box right click it.
3. Then **select Properties** from the menu.
4. Find **ListFillRange** & insert Source data 
   Range (A155:A164).
5. Find **ListStyle box**, select **1-fmList 
   StyleOption.**
6. Then select **1–fmMultiSelectMulti** from the 
   **MultiSelect.**
7. Then select any specified cell (E155), then 
   name it as **ListBoxOutput.**
8. Then Click **Insert, Shapes** and draw an 
   appropriate (C155) shape above the List Box.
9. Then **right click the Shape** & select 
   **Assign Macro (Rectangle2_Click)** from the 
   menu.

*Insert the below written code as Module.*

```
Sub Rectangle2_Click()

Dim xSelShp As Shape, xSelLst As Variant, I As Integer

Set xSelShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
Set xLstBox = ActiveSheet.ListBox1

If xLstBox.Visible = False Then
    xLstBox.Visible = True
    xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Click After Pickup Options"
Else
    xLstBox.Visible = False
    xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Click To Select Options"

    For I = xLstBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If xLstBox.Selected(I) = True Then
        xSelLst = xLstBox.List(I) & "," & xSelLst
        End If
    Next I

    If xSelLst <> "" Then
        Range("ListBoxOutput") = Mid(xSelLst, 1, Len(xSelLst) - 1)
    Else
        Range("ListBoxOutput") = ""
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

10. **Click the Shape to open List box**, select 
     items and again **click the Shape** to put 
     selected items in Cell `E155`.

**Note,** *adjust cell references for Source item 
  list, List box, Shape's position & for 
  Output cell also.*

Comment: Gald to help you Gabriel,,, keep asing ☺